# Undefined index: path, when adding new custom service provider in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, voyager

I want to add new custom service provider to set session_lifetime. The value for it, I got it from database. For do this thing I create service provider. But after the service provider registered. I got and error like this : `Undefined index: path`.

[image]

This is my new service provider code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ParameterSettingServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Bootstrap services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{

}

/**
 * Register services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    if (\Schema::hasTable('parameter_settings')) {
        $settings = DB::table('parameter_settings')->first();
        if ($settings) //checking if table is not empty
        {
            $config = array(
                'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
                'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', $settings->session_expired),
                'expire_on_close' => true,
            );
            Config::set('session', $config);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my `config/app.php` to register the service provider :

```
    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\ParameterSettingServiceProvider::class,
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Can you post the full error and stacktrace?

Comment: I would guess that the `Undefined index: path` is referring to the setting for session/cookies in `config/session.php`.

Comment: you would do this in `boot` not `register` if you were going to do something like this and i wouldn't be calling `env` outside config files

Comment: @Jerodev I have put screenshot the error

Comment: @lagbox, I have tried it, to put it in `boot`, but i got this error `Undefined index: lottery`

Comment: @lagbox, I have tried to set one value and not use `env` like your suggestion before, just lifetime like this `'lifetime' => $settings->session_expired,`, but i get error like this `Session store not set on request`

Comment: that isn't how you set a single configuration value that is in an array ... this new error is because you are trying to access the session to early in the lifecycle ... there is no session at all until the `StartSession` middleware has ran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `boot` method of the Service Provider not the `register` method. The `boot` method of the Provider will run after all other Service Provider's `register` methods have ran.

If you only want to set 1 single configuration value, you can do that. You don't need to overwrite the entire `session` config key (which holds 15 vars, check your `config/session.php` file). This is why you will keep getting errors about undefined indexes because these configuration variables need to exist.

The documentation's example for setting a config value at run time is how you set a single key by name (using the "dot" syntax):

```
Config::set('session.lifetime', $settings->session_expired);
```

[Laravel 5.8 Docs - Configuration - Accessing Configuration Values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration#accessing-configuration-values)